# Eclipse suggests Null Pointer exception, though I believe I initialized my object

Tags: java, eclipse, nullpointerexception

As the title says I have NPE error. It happens on line:

```
while (getWidth() > bowl.getX()+10) {
```

If I remove it, it shows it happens on next line:

```
bowl.move(10.0, 0);
```

I concluded that eclipse does not see my "bowl" initialized.
Why? Doesn't "new GOval" deal with that?
I've seen in one of the threads here that a solution was to split declaration and initialization to different lines, but I think it is unlikely to be a primary solution (besides, it didn't help in my case) Any suggestions on this code?

This code is supposed to create a circle, put it in the left-upper corner of the screen, and move the circle after mouse-button is clicked. The circle is drawn successfully, but the NPE message shows up after the click.

```
import acm.program.*;
import acm.graphics.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class animation extends GraphicsProgram {

public void init() {
    GOval bowl = new GOval(10,10);
    add(bowl);
    addMouseListeners();
}


public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        while (getWidth() > bowl.getX()+10) {
        bowl.move(10.0, 0);
        pause(50);
    }
}

private GOval bowl; 
}
```

Comment: yeah =) Again, never meant to offend eclipse.probably the title should rather be. I still believe I initialized the object, even though Eclipse says I have an error ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line:

```
GOval bowl = new GOval(10,10);
```

is declaring a new GOval and hiding the global GOval defined at the bottom.

That line should just be:

```
bowl = new GOval(10,10);
```

Comment: @Andrew Stubbs Wow. I was struggling on this for so long! Thanks! It helped!

Comment: @rcook, I never said eclipse was wrong. That would be too arrogant. I only said I believed I initialized the object.

Comment: Not saying eclipse was wrong is a little different from trusting that it is correct.  Finding a bug, like finding other things that you are having trouble seeing, is made easier if you're convinced of where it is in the first place.  Other languages and systems have tended to make many of us distrust error messages, and I was just pointing out that Java messages almost always point us in the right direction.

Answer (score 4):

You are shadowing your `bowl` field at the class level in the `init` method,

```
private GOval bowl; 

public void init() {
  // GOval bowl = new GOval(10,10);
  bowl = new GOval(10,10);
  add(bowl);
  addMouseListeners();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Like most people already mentioned you are shadowing your bowl variable.

```
GOval bowl = new GOval(10,10);
```

should be replaced with

```
bowl = new GOval(10,10);
```

You can configure eclipse that he gives you a warning when you are doing this. In the preferences you have a dedicated part for this under java -> compiler -> errors/warnings